# Effective matrix slicing with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply sub-matrix on a sub-vector. It seems that such multiplication should be faster that multiplication of a whole matrix on a whole vector, but time measurements say opposite:

```
B = np.random.randn(26200, 2000)
h = np.random.randn(2000)
%time z = B @ h
CPU times: user 56 ms, sys: 4 ms, total: 60 ms
Wall time: 29.4 ms

%time z = B[:, :256] @ h[:256]
CPU times: user 44 ms, sys: 28 ms, total: 72 ms
Wall time: 54.5 ms
```

Results with %timeit:

```
%timeit z = B @ h
100 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop

%timeit z = B[:, :256] @ h[:256]
10 loops, best of 3: 38.2 ms per loop
```

Running it again:

```
%timeit z = B @ h
10 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop 

%timeit z = B[:, :256] @ h[:256]
10 loops, best of 3: 36.8 ms per loop
```

May be there are some effective way to do it with numpy, or may be I need to use for example tenserflow to make this slicing effective?

Comment: `%timeit` should be a more reliable method.

Comment: @Divakar results of timeit still show that multiplication of a whole matrix is faster

Comment: I am not convinced that you are getting those results, as the edits between `%time` and `%timeit` show no change in timings to the last decimal place. To me that looked like a manual edit and hence a typo error in posting timing results.

Comment: @Divakar if it is so important, I've first copied text above, then changed output of functions copying it from my code and then change time to timeit (just to make copying faster) and forgot to change for one of them. Clear, output of time and timeit is different.

Comment: Can you run `%timeit z = B[:, :256] @ h[:256]` once more and tell us if you are getting it around that mark `38.2ms`?

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. I can't reproduce those at my end as the sliced version is about 50% faster than full version for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of memory layout and time access. By default, [arrays are stored line by line like in C](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray)  (`order='C')`. You can store your data column by column like in Fortran (`order='F'`), more compatible with your restricted problem, since you select only few columns.

Ilustration :

```
In [107]: BF=np.asfortranarray(B)

In [108]: np.equal(B,BF).all()
Out[108]: True


In [110]: %timeit B@h
78.5 ms ± 20.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [111]: %timeit BF@h
89.3 ms ± 7.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [112]: %timeit B[:,:256]@h[:256]
150 ms ± 18.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [113]: %timeit BF[:,:256]@h[:256]
10.5 ms ± 893 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This way time execution follows size.